# Terraform azurerm data source resource group no object id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create a role assignment which allows a resource group to contribute to a static ip adresse.
The role assignment looks like the following:

```
  resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "public_ip_role" {
  scope                            = azurerm_public_ip.ingress_nginx.id
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_aks.object_id
}
```

The data source looks like this:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_aks" {
  name = "aks-my-${var.environment}"
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "object_id".
```

Comment: Can you add the data source to the question as well?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation [1] it should be only `.id`:

```
  resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "public_ip_role" {
  scope                            = azurerm_public_ip.ingress_nginx.id
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_aks.id
}
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, the error is not only because a wrong attribute of a data source is being accessed, rather a completely wrong data source is being used. As per the documentation [2], it should be `azurerm_client_config`:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resource_group#id

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment#example-usage-using-a-built-in-role

Comment: I tried this and ran into this error:The Principal ID '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/aks-my-dev' is not valid. Principal ID must be a GUID."

Comment: Based on the example https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment#example-usage-using-a-built-in-role you are using a wrong resource for that. It should be `azurerm_client_config` not `azurerm_resource_group`.

Comment: azurerm_client_config assigns the users object_id to the principal_id instead of the resource groups object_id.

Comment: There is no `object_id` attribute provided by the `azurerm_resource_group` data source.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way which works in this specific case.
The principal_id which should be used is the one of a resource group created automatically by azure when creating a k8s cluster.
I found out that the principal_id of this resource group can be found when inside the state of the created cluster.
To find the id one has to find the cluster with "terraform state list" and then "terraform state show *clusterName*".
The principal_id is under identity so it can be referenced with

```
azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.identity[0].principal_id
```